# React Immutable JS updateIn with list key in object

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, setstate

I have an immutable state in React, where I have an map containing list elements.

My getIn function works correctly, e.g.:

```
console.log(this.state.settings.getIn(["airlines"])[index].checked);
```

But I want to update this value with the reverse.

Reading the docs of immutable JS, it should be something like this, but due to my index key I can't get it to work, since my update val should be within the ().

What I currently have is something like this:

```
this.state.settings.updateIn((["airlines"])[index].checked, val => !val);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass path to updated property as array. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ogqdp4ey/1/).

```
this.state.settings.updateIn(['airlines', index, 'checked'], val => !val);
```

BTW The same works with `getIn`. You can do

```
console.log(this.state.settings.getIn(['airlines', index, 'checked']));
```

Comment: The getIn suggested by you gives me an undefined, where the solution I wrote gives me the correct value. btw. it is an array of objects inside an (settings) object. Are you sure this is the correct way?

Comment: If it gives you `undefined` it is `undefined`. I'm 100% sure. Check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ogqdp4ey/1/

Comment: but it is a bit different in my case.. in my state I have a "settings" map, in which objects are (like airlines). Within airlines, indeed there is an array.

Comment: It doesn't matter how nested your structure is. https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/2ezq6n7w/

Comment: really strange, I do see your code working, but if I do console.log(settings.getIn(['airlines'])) I do get an array of objects, but if I add index to it  - console.log(settings.getIn(['airlines',index])) - , it will return undefined, although console.log of index is correct, e.g. 0. And if I do: console.log(this.state.getIn(['settings','airlines',index])); - I get "this.state.getIn is not a function"

Comment: Hmm thats totally unexpected. Could you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: That was quite some work ;-) but here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/d3z00v8o/3/ Thnx already!

Comment: Setter does not automatically convert values to collections. You need to call constuctor manually or use `fromJS` http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/d3z00v8o/5/

Comment: Great! indeed fromJS does the trick! but if I want to update values in this array, e.g. a checked value of one item.. do I need fromJS then as well?

Comment: Well using arrays will ruin the whole benefit of immutability. You will  loose referential transparency if you simply modify one of its elements. To avoid this you'll need to recreate entire array `settings.updateIn(['airlines'], airlines => airlines.map((item, i) => i === index ? {...item, checked: !item.checked}:item))`. But it kinda ruins the whole point of using ImmutableJS. :)